# How do template instantiations get compiled by Clang?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, llvm

I am using *Clang as a library* to compile some templated code:

```
template<typename T>
T getSevenTemplated() {
  return 7;
}

int getSeven() {
  return getSevenTemplated<int>();
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiled LLVM IR does not actually contain the implementation of `getSevenTemplated<int>`:

```
; ModuleID = './test.cpp'
source_filename = "./test.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0"

; Function Attrs: ssp uwtable
define i32 @_Z8getSevenv() #0 {
entry:
  %call = call i32 @_Z17getSevenTemplatedIiET_v()
  ret i32 %call
}

declare i32 @_Z17getSevenTemplatedIiET_v() #1

attributes #0 = { ssp uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="penryn" "target-features"="+cx16,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,+ssse3,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="penryn" "target-features"="+cx16,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,+ssse3,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"clang version 5.0.0 (trunk 292778)"}
```

Here is the code I am using to generate the LLVM module:

```
auto* context = new llvm::LLVMContext(); // TODO: Fix leak 

auto codeGenerator =
  std::shared_ptr<clang::CodeGenerator>(
    clang::CreateLLVMCodeGen(
      compilerInstance.getDiagnostics(), 
      filePath,
      compilerInstance.getHeaderSearchOpts(), 
      preprocessor.getPreprocessorOpts(),
      compilerInstance.getCodeGenOpts(), 
      *context, 
      nullptr));

codeGenerator->Initialize(compilerInstance.getASTContext());

// declGroups are found by calling ParseAST with a special ASTConsumer earlier
for (auto declGroup : declGroups) { 
  codeGenerator->HandleTopLevelDecl(declGroup);
}

codeGenerator->HandleTranslationUnit(compilerInstance.getASTContext());
```

To investigate why, I looked through [the source-code](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CodeGenModule_8cpp_source.html#l03753) and I found that the `CodeGenerator` has specific logic for handling templates: it seems to skip function template instantiations! I presume that it handles the generated functions instead, but I don't know how it really works.

My questions are:

1. At a high level, how does Clang go about instantiating templates and passing them to the `ASTConsumer` for code generation?
2. Are there any special tricks for enabling the generation of function bodies for instantiated templates? What am I missing from the code above?

Comment: You seem to be trying to instantiate a function and call it at the same time.  Are you trying to return the number 7 or the function that returns int?

Comment: @stark I want to generate the LLVM IR for the above program

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I had incremental parsing turned on. With this setting enabled, the `ParseAST` function does not call `clang::Sema::ActOnEndOfTranslationUnit`, which triggers the instantiation of templates.

The trick is to add this call after processing your decls:

```
// This triggers the instantiation of templated functions
sema.ActOnEndOfTranslationUnit();
```